# Why do I need a reputation above 50 to answer?

Tags: support, reputation

Why is it necessary to get 50 reputation before answering a question?

Comment: Sure. What should I do next? Delete this question?

Comment: Your choice but yes, you can delete it here but first post in meta.

Comment: Possibly you mean the "[comment everywhere](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment)" priviliege? Submitting answers to questions is not limited by reputation points. It's a way to earn them.